# My program reads 0 from the database even though there is a 1

Tags: c++, mysql

I don't understand whats wrong with the code, I have read a lot of times but I can't find the error

```
pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT (?) FROM votos WHERE id = (?)");
pstmt->setString(1, eleccion);
pstmt->setInt(2, p->getId());
res = pstmt->executeQuery();
while(res->next())
{
    p->setVoto(res->getInt(1));
}
```

When the `eleccion` and `id` variables are `Provincial` and `1` respectively the getInt(1) function should return 1, but it returns 0.

The command (in the mysql command line):

`SELECT Provincial from Votos WHERE id=1`

Returns a table with one row and one column with the value 1

Side notes:

Spelling was checked

The getId() function works correctly

The compiler doesn't give any error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour. Valid SO question. End of reviewing. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: You cannot bind a variable as a field name in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a placeholder in a prepared query for a column name. It's returning the value of the string `eleccion`, not using it as the name of a column in the table. You need to do string concatenation to substitute the column name.

```
std::string sql = std::string("SELECT `") + eleccion + "` FROM votos WHERE id = ?";
pstmt = con->prepareStatement(sql.c_str());
pstmt->setInt(1, p->getId());
res = pstmt->executeQuery();
while(res->next())
{
    p->setVoto(res->getInt(1));
}
```

If the value of `eleccion` is coming from the user or some other untrusted source, make sure you validate it before concatenating, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. The error is (apparently) solved, I now have an internal server error (end of the script output before headers) Edit: I solved it

Comment: Worth to mention that you may have opened the door to SQL injections now. The safe way to do this is with a whitelist of column names.